# Hostname and /etc/hosts keep changing to instance/project name after network restart. Need to have a fixed hostname setting

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Engine/VM running the Google provided OS image for CentOS 7 (x86_64 built on 2016-12-12) and keep running into issues of hostname and /etc/hosts getting changed by some custom modification/service being done by Google.

Google documents the details about their image on their [site here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) in there it says in pertinent part

> The hostname is set via a DHCP exit hook and will be re-configured to match the instance name anytime the network is brought up.

Here lies the problem, my instance does not seem to have those scripts that I can change or override this behavior - I already setup my applications on this image so I would rather not download the public centos image and go that way when all I need is to remove this "hack" they built-into their image.

Looking for DHCP init scripts and did not find anything in these folders:

```
[root@cponly2 dhcp]# pwd
/etc/dhcp
[root@cponly2 dhcp]# ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-x---.  3 root root  23 Dec 23 23:47 .
drwxr-xr-x. 87 root root 12K Dec 24 01:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  45 Dec 23 23:41 dhclient.d
[root@cponly2 dhcp]# ls -lah dhclient.d/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   45 Dec 23 23:41 .
drwxr-x---. 3 root root   23 Dec 23 23:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.2K Nov 14 16:18 ntp.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   41 Dec 23 23:41 set_hostname.sh
```

I tried to add a script set_hostname.sh to change the hostname without success.

I also tried to set the hostname via metadata but upon rebooting the VM/instance the hostname does not get set properly. I have verified the metadata exists from:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

is not returning the "custom metadata" I set for this specific VM, but keeps returning the instance-name.c.project-id.internal

/var/log/messages when restarting networking looks like this:

```
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 systemd: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): lo: link is not ready
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.4466] device (lo): link connected
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 network: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6687] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (18214b23-9ad6-45df-9a5d-41355fa07c59)
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6688] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="18214b23-9ad6-45df-9a5d-41355fa07c59" name="eth0" pid=25261 uid=0 result="success"
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6689] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6690] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6692] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6890] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.6896] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7046] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 25268
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 dhclient[25268]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xba5315d)
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 dhclient[25268]: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254 (xid=0xba5315d)
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7352] dhcp4 (eth0):   address 10.142.0.2
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   plen 32 (255.255.255.255)
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   classless static route 10.142.0.1/32 gw 0.0.0.0
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   gateway 10.142.0.1
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   server identifier 169.254.169.254
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   lease time 86400
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   hostname 'cponly2.c.test.internal'
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   nameserver '169.254.169.254'
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7355] dhcp4 (eth0):   domain name 'c.test.internal.'
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7356] dhcp (eth0):   domain search 'c.test.internal.'
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7356] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 NetworkManager[543]: <info>  [1482613538.7363] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 avahi-daemon[342]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.142.0.2.
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 avahi-daemon[342]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 24 21:05:38 cponly2 avahi-daemon[342]: Registering new address record for 10.142.0.2 on eth0.IPv4.
```

So this makes me believe the NetworkManager is in use, further checking on the settings it looks like ifcfg-rh plugin is the one. Reading on some [NetworkManager settings documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/SystemSettings) for "ifcfg-rh" plugin the persistent hostname setting is pulled from /etc/hostname and falls back to /etc/sysconfig/network 'hostname' both of them are set to the hostname I want yet Google Compute engine continues to fallback on its internal name.

Don't know what else to try here, thanks in advance for help on this.